# AngularJS getting data from JSON local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I'm having troubles retrieving the data from json file using the following structure. 
In my controller.js file I have:

```
var controllers = angular.module('hotels.controllers', []);

controllers.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

   $scope.list;

   $http.get('json-folder/name.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.list = data.data;
    console.log(data);


});
```

And in that name.json file I have the following structure:

```
{
   "hotel": [
     {
       "id": 1,
        "name": "Some hotel name",
        "address": "123 Street",
        "category" : [{
            "id": 1,
            "name" : "Category 1",
            "bnb" : "yes",
            "simple" : "some value",
            "double" : "another value"
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name" : "Category 2",
            "bnb" : "no",
            "simple" : "some value 2",
            "double" : "another value 2"
         },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name" : "Category 3",
            "bnb" : "no",
            "simple" : "some value 3",
            "double" : "another value 3"
         }
         ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Some hotel name 2",
        "address": "33333 Street",
        "category" : [{
             "id": 1,
             "name" : "Category 1",
             "bnb" : "yes",
             "simple" : "some value",
             "double" : "another value"
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name" : "Category 2",
            "bnb" : "no",
            "simple" : "some value 2",
            "double" : "another value 2"
         },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name" : "Category 3",
            "bnb" : "no",
            "simple" : "some value 3",
            "double" : "another value 3"
         }
        ]  
        }
    ],
    "motel": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Some motel name",
          "address": "321 Street",
          "category" : [{
              "id" : 1,
              "name" : "Category Motel 1",
              "bnb" : "yes",
              "simple" : "some motel value",
              "double" : "another motel value"
           },
           {
             "id" : 2,
             "name" : "Category Motel 2",
             "bnb" : "no",
             "simple" : "some motel value 2",
             "double" : "another motel value 2"
           }
           ]
       }
     ]
}
```

and finally my html structure:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <li class="pull-left" ng-repeat="hotel in list.hotels">
            {{hotel.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ng-controller="CatCtrl">
      <ul class="pull-right">
          <li class="pull-right" ng-repeat="cat in list.categories">
              {{cat.name}}
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I don't get anything back and I don't have any errors... 
What I want to have is one ul li with the name of the hotels and in another similar div I would like to have again list with categories names along with other data from categories under hotel. Please note that CatCtrl is the same as AppCtrl...

Any idea what I am doing wrong for first one, and what should I change in other controller to get what I need?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `$scope.list = data.data` be `$scope.list = data` instead? `data` is meant to be the JSON itself already

Comment: and `list` has no properties `hotels` or `categories` .. it has `hotel` and `motel`. Not clear at all what you want `categories` array to look like

Comment: some tiny changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZV2TG7FATs7NoRIjF18?p=preview

Comment: @lucasnadalutti if I remove that data I get the first one correct

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, what I want is to loop through hotel categories and display them on the page. I already have names from first suggestion.

Comment: @ABOS wow, nice one, let me check in more details that code... thanks.

Comment: Then you need to map new array and get all the categories out of existing array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you got the first part right, getting the categories should require the code to be changed to:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul class="pull-left">
        <li class="pull-left" ng-repeat="hotel in list.hotel">
            {{hotel.name}}
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li class="pull-right" ng-repeat="cat in hotel.category">
                    {{cat.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'll rely on your CSS skills to arrange the display correctly.

Comment: I get this error in my editor: unresolved variable hotel.

Comment: Try `list.hotels` then instead. In your original code you used `list.hotels` but the property was `hotel` in the JSON you provided, so I was unsure. Probably the same with `category`/`categories`.

Comment: Ok, I changed but nothing happened and I added that s to hotel, so it is hotels in json now and also motels... What should I try next? I don't get any output on page regarding categories...

Comment: Note that `category` in `cat in hotel.category` should also be the same as `category` inside each `hotel` in your JSON. In case the property name is `categories`, it should also be changed accordingly. Even so, no luck?

Comment: Still nothing, so in JSON I have `hotels` instead of `hotel` and `categories` instead of `category` and then I have it like you said: `ng-repeat="cat in hotels.categories"` and finally `{{cat.name}}` and I don't get anything back.

Comment: Hm, that's really odd. I'd need your current code in a plunkr so we could investigate further.

Comment: Only first loop works, I mean I changed there as well from hotel to hotels...  Not sure what should I try next... Here you can check the code http://plnkr.co/edit/RFfKjxBcgKW4ktcH2LOf?p=preview

Comment: I see now that your plunkr was not exactly as I recommended. You had `li` inside `li`, without being wrapped in `ul`. I fixed it and now you can see it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/oPPOP9rhqGaLQxsCn1jo?p=preview

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will check how this will go with real data.